# Redirection on click of OK and close the window on click of Cancel button in msgbox

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a vbscript where I am displaying a message in a message box along with OK and cancel buttons.

I want to redirect the user to some other page when he clicks OK and also i want the browser tab to close if he clicks on cancel button.

How do I achieve this? Below is my code.

```
<% dim message
message = "Access granted"
Response.Write("<script language=VBScript>MsgBox """ + message +""",""1"",""Access Alert""</script>") 
%>
```

Comment: i have to use vbscript only

Comment: May I ask why? I am presuming it is a web page